# send c-like struct as arrayBuffer via udp chrome socket

Tags: google-chrome, ionic-framework, websocket, udp, arraybuffer

i'm using chrome.sockets to send udp messages.
i need to send this c-like struct:

```
UInt16 ID=0, 
UInt Size=20,
UInt16 CRC=0, 
UInt16 MsgCount=0,
UInt32 App=0,
UInt32 Port=55555,
UInt32 Token=0
```

the chrome.udp.send needs to get an arrayBuffer.
what i did in my code is this:

```
var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(20);
var dv = new DataView(arrayBuffer,0);
dv.setUint16(0,0);
dv.setUint16(2,20);
dv.setUint16(4,0);
dv.setUint16(6,0);
dv.setUint32(8,0);
dv.setUint32(12,55555);
dv.setUint32(16,0);
```

but when i

```
console.log(arrayBuffer);
```

i get

```
ArrayBuffer {}
```

it is empty.

How can i send a c-like struct like this correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayBuffer` stores bytes - any byte values at all.

`console.log()` expects human-readable ASCII strings, so that it can display them.

Unfortunately, logging an `ArrayBuffer` doesn't help - as soon as there's an ASCII NUL character (and your data has one in the *very first byte*) the string stops. You will need to write a different function to accept an `ArrayBuffer` and produce a Hex `string` that you can pass to `console.log()`

Comment: thanks for the comment, i did it this way: console.log(dv.getUint16(0));
          console.log(dv.getUint16(2));
          console.log(dv.getUint16(4));
          console.log(dv.getUint16(6));
          console.log(dv.getUint32(8));
          console.log(dv.getUint32(12));
          console.log(dv.getUint32(16));